# Узнать кто вызвал модуль

Tags: node.js, node-modules

Есть модуль обращения к сервису. Например getData.js, и есть куча других модулей, которые используют его. Как можно узнать кто вызвал модуль getData (в идеале получить путь). `module.parent` возвращает только путь к первому модулю, который вызвал

Comment: `new Error().stack`

Comment: А что значит «вызвал модуль»? Сделал `require('./getData.js')`?

Comment: @AlexeyTen, да.

Comment: Ну без залезания совсем в «кишки» ноды никак. Во второй и далее вызовы requre  возвращает закешированный модуль и вообще ничего не выполняет